# How to get Fody / PropertyChanged to work in an iOS project in Xamarin Studio?

Tags: xamarin.ios, fody, fody-propertychanged

I've installed Nuget for Xamarin Studio and tried to add [Fody/PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) to my iOS solution. However I get the following error:

```
Adding 'PropertyChanged.Fody 1.41.0.0' to ImapClientApp.iOS.
Could not install package 'PropertyChanged.Fody 1.41.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoTouch,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not install package 'PropertyChanged.Fody 1.41.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoTouch,Version=v1.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
  at NuGet.ProjectManager.ExtractPackageFilesToProject (IPackage package) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Does somebody know how to get it to cooperate with iOS solutions?

Comment: You don't have a PCL that you're trying to put this into?

Comment: Try version 1.29.4. That's the one I'm currently using. I had some issues with the latest versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following nuget package for Fody. Have used it successfully in my project.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Fody/